# Shooting Method with extra Unknown Condition

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, finite-element-method, boundary-conditions

I've been trying to solve a system of 3 coupled 2nd order ODEs, for a real variable $x$, $0\geq x\leq \infty$. The equations are the following:
\begin{align}
&x^{2}\,h''(x) - x\,h'(x) + x^{2}\,g^{2}(x)\left[1-h(x)\right] = 0\,,\\
&x^{2}\,f''(x) + x\,f'(x) - \lambda\, x^{2}\,f(x)\left[f^{2}(x) + g^{2}(x) - 2\right] = 0\,,\\
&x^{2}\,g''(x) + x\,g'(x) - \frac{1}{2}\,g(x)\left[1-h(x)\right]^{2} - \lambda\, x^{2}g(x)\left[f^{2}(x) + g^{2}(x) - 2\right] = 0\,.
\end{align}

In addition, the BCs are (where my problem starts):
$$h(0)=0=g(0)\,, \quad f(0)=\Omega$$
and
$$h(x\to\infty)=f(x\to\infty)=g(x\to\infty)=1\,.$$

First of all, I decided to solve to some finite $x$ such as $x_{max}$ and then try to increase this domain. Then, my problem consists of how I should "tell" NDSolve that I don't know the value $\Omega$ is going to have. I know that, somehow, the numerical solution must find an appropriate value for $\Omega$ that agrees with the whole solution. But I cannot understand how I can do this. My starting code is the following:

```
lambda = 0.5; 
eps = 0.001;
xmax = 5;
eq1=x^2*h''[x] - x*h'[x] + x^2*(g[x]^2) (1 - h[x]);
eq2= x^2*f''[x] + x*f'[x] - lambda*x^2*f[x] ((f[x]^2) + (g[x]^2) - 2);
eq3= x^2*g''[x] + x*g'[x] -  1/2*g[x] (1 - h[x])^2 - lambda*x^2*g[x] ((f[x]^2) + (g[x]^2) - 
2);
    
sols=First[NDSolve[{eq1==0,eq2==0, eq3== 0,h[eps] == 0,f[eps] == Omega, g[eps]==0}, {f[x], 
g[x], h[x]}, {x, eps, xmax},Method -> {"Shooting","StartingInitialConditions" -> {h[eps] == 
0,f[eps] == Omega, g[eps] == 0}}, WorkingPrecision -> 5]];
```

As you can see, my code is incomplete. The shooting method would need 6 initial conditions for the (converted) IVP -> 3 from the BC at $x=0$ and the shooting for the 3 first-order derivatives. However, since I don't know (a priori) the value of $\Omega$, *I'm stuck* :(

Ps.: From my problem, I know I can put by hand that all the first-order derivatives go to zero when $x\to\infty$... But this would add too many conditions for Mathematica, right?

Could you, please, provide any advice on how I can tackle the problem?

Comment: For problems like these, it might be better to use a mesh and apply Newton's cooling method starting from an initial guess for the solution, rather than using the shooting method.

Comment: Hi @QuantumDot. I do not have experience with numerical solutions. Would this "Newton's cooling method" similar to what Numerical Recipes call *Relaxation*? And I have tried to solve this by shooting because the paper I was reading told the readers those equations were solved by a shooting method together with a 5th order RK for integration. However, I can try to learn relaxation, too. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `NDSolve` and `Method -> "Shooting"`, I was unable to integrate past `x = 2.93`.  With `Method -> "FiniteElement"`, I was able to integrate as far as `x = 7.5`, but `omega` could only be approximated.  In general, the problem appeared to be inadequate numerical accuracy near `x = 0.` The following worked much better.

First, obtain approximate symbolic solutions near `x = 0`

```
sh0 = DSolveValue[{eq1 == 0, h[0] == 0} /. {f[x]^2 -> omega^2, g[x]^2 -> 0}, h[x], x] /.
    C[1] -> ch
(* (ch x^2)/2 *)

sf0 = Simplify[DSolveValue[{eq2 == 0, f[0] == omega} /. {f[x]^2 -> omega^2, g[x]^2 -> 0},
    f[x], x], omega^2 < 2]
(* omega BesselJ[0, (Sqrt[2 - omega^2] x)/Sqrt[2]] *)

sg0 = Simplify[DSolveValue[{eq3 == 0, g[0] == 0} /. {f[x]^2 -> omega^2,
    g[x]^2 -> 0, h[x] -> 0}, g[x], x], omega^2 < 2] /. C[1] -> cg
(* cg (BesselJ[1/Sqrt[2], (Sqrt[2 - omega^2] x)/Sqrt[2]] - (BesselJ[1/Sqrt[2], 0] 
   BesselY[1/Sqrt[2], (Sqrt[2 - omega^2] x)/Sqrt[2]])/BesselY[1/Sqrt[2], 0]) *)
```

Then, obtain the three parameters `{omega, cg, ch}` by what might be called do-it-yourself shooting, with the symbolic solutions near `x = 0` as initial conditions.

```
xmax = 10; eps = .1;
sp = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eq1 == 0, eq2 == 0, eq3 == 0, 
    {f[x] == sf0, g[x] == sg0, h[x] == sh0, f'[x] == D[sf0, x], g'[x] == D[sg0, x], 
    h'[x] == D[sh0, x]} /. x -> eps}, {f[xmax], g[xmax], h[xmax]}, {x, eps, xmax}, 
    {omega, cg, ch}, PrecisionGoal -> 10, AccuracyGoal -> 10];

FindRoot[sp[omega, cg, ch] - 1, {{omega, 1.35617}, {cg, 1.3415}, {ch, 0.325786}}, 
    Evaluated -> False]
(* {omega -> 1.35617, cg -> 1.3415, ch -> 0.325786} *)
```

Finally, compute and solve the equations with the parameters just determined.

```
NDSolveValue[{eq1 == 0, eq2 == 0, eq3 == 0, {f[x] == sf0, g[x] == sg0, h[x] == sh0, 
  f'[x] == D[sf0, x], g'[x] == D[sg0, x], h'[x] == D[sh0, x]} /. x -> eps} /. %, 
  {f[x], g[x], h[x]}, {x, eps, xmax}];
Plot[%, {x, eps, xmax}, ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {x, "f,g,h"},
    LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

The initial guesses for `FindRoot` were obtained by integrating the equations for `xmax = 3` and using the result as guesses for `xmax = 4`, etc.  Note that even `xmax = 10` is not in the asymptotic domain of the equations.  Increasing `xmax` to, say `20` undoubtedly would require higher `WorkingPrecision` and an automated process for gradually increasing `xmax`, both of which are feasible.

Comment: Thank you so much! It has helped me a lot.

Comment: @bbgodfrey The term `sp[omega, cg, ch] - 1` in `FindRoot`, why is there a `-1`? Also, supposedly you didn't have much idea on the problem how did you choose your starting point for `FindRoot`? I have tried changing the initial point a bit and it produced errors like `ParametricNDSolveValue::ndsz` `InterpolatingFunction::dmval` `FindRoot::lstol`

Comment: @mathemania `1` is the desired asymptotic value for the three dependent variables.  I used `FindRoot` to obtain initial conditions that achieved this value for my solution.  The final paragraph of my answer explains how I obtained my initial guesses.